# This account is currently not available

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, flock

**Anyone know why `case1` is not working properly as `case2` ?**

```
-case0:
#:/cloud/dahua# sudo -u sysUser echo hello
hello

-case1:
#: sudo -u sysUser flock -xn hello.lock -c "echo hello"
This account is currently not available.

-case2:
#:/cloud/dahua# sudo -u sysUser flock -xn hello.lock echo hello
hello

#:/cloud/dahua# cat /etc/passwd | grep sysUser
sysUser:x:1001:1001::/home/sysUser:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

**Anyone know why `case1` is not working properly as `case2` ?**

NAME         top
flock - manage locks from shell scripts
DESCRIPTION         top
This utility manages flock(2) locks from within shell scripts or
from the command line.

```
   The first and second of the above forms wrap the lock around the
   execution of a command, in a manner similar to su(1) or
   newgrp(1). They lock a specified file or directory, which is
   created (assuming appropriate permissions) if it does not already
   exist. By default, if the lock cannot be immediately acquired,
   flock waits until the lock is available.

   The third form uses an open file by its file descriptor number.
   See the examples below for how that can be used.
```

OPTIONS         top
-c, --command command
Pass a single command, without arguments, to the shell with
-c.